# Need to create triggers for audit tracking, getting "incorrect syntax?"

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have one table `Products` on which i need to create trigger to update changes (new data) in data in another table `Products_audit` which has same columns with same data.

I've tried following:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Super 

ON Products 

AFTER INSERT, UPDATE

AS

UPDATE Product_audit (Column1,Column2, Column3, ... )

SELECT (Column1,Column2,Column3,...)

FROM Products
```

Receiving the following error:

```
Server: Msg 170, Level 15, State 31, Procedure Super, Line 20
Line 20: Incorrect syntax near '('.
Server: Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Super, Line 24
Line 24: Incorrect syntax near ','.
```

I use sql server 2000

I'm not so strong else in triggers creation could you please correct me I'd like to know where was I wrong ?

Comment: At first glance I'd say that you shouldn't have parenthesis in the select-clause.

Comment: Yeah I removed them thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you trigger need to look like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Super 

ON Products 

AFTER INSERT, UPDATE

AS

UPDATE Product_audit 

SET Column1 = p.Column1
SET Column2 = p.Column2

FROM Products p
```

Comment: Was this helpful on anyway?

Comment: Nope receiving following:  Server: Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Super1, Line 29
Line 29: Incorrect syntax near '@UnitsInStock'.
Server: Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Super1, Line 46
Line 46: Incorrect syntax near 'UnitsInStock'.
Don't know where I was wrong

Comment: Put concrete effort to see what you are written.

Answer (score 0):

Hello you have to create two different trigger one for update and one for insert 
1) For Insert

```
CREATE TRIGGER Super
ON Products
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO Product_audit 
(Column1,Column2,...)
SELECT Column1,Column2,...
FROM Inserted

END
```

2) For Update

```
 CREATE TRIGGER Super
    ON Products
    AFTER Update
    AS
    BEGIN

    DECLARE @Column1 as varchar(10)
    DECLARE @Column2 as varchar(10)
    DECLARE @ID INT

    SELECT @ID=ID,@Column1=Column1,@Column2=Column2 FROM INSERTED 



   UPDATE Product_audit  SET Column1=@Column1,Column2=@Column2
   WHERE ID=@ID

    END
```

Comment: And please explain me what does it mean that variable @ID=ID ?

Comment: And may be did you mean FROM UPDATED instead FROM INSERTED    ?         SELECT @ID=ID,@Column1=Column1,@Column2=Column2 FROM INSERTED